# Entity Component System, How to decouple components need for entity as parameter?

Tags: entity-system

I use [Artemis entity system framework, C# port](https://github.com/thelinuxlich/artemis_CSharp). I have problem with figuring out a good way to handle items and using them.

Game is AI driven mostly, so it's not the player that is interacting, but AI. AI is basically Entity with `AIBehaviorComponent` that is ran by `AISystem`. AI has helper functions that allows it to find all items (ie. Entities with `InteractiveComponent`) and then it can pathfind to it and use that item. AI is using `BehaviorTree` that is stored in it's component.

I have `InteractiveComponent`that allows player and AI to `Use` entity. I have this thing working, but it looks a bit dirty solution. `Use` method is interface that is implemented by Item object that is tied to that component. This way i can have item made with:

```
new InteractiveComponent(new AwesomeItem());
```

Calling `Use` requires me to:

1. Get entity ref
2. Find component 'InteractiveComponent`
3. interactiveComponent.use(me)

`me` is (this) Entity. The AI entity that is calling the use. I am passing entity to `Use` method, because using something can alter the entity. It could add component to it, check if it has certain component and then modify the data or remove components, it could even remove the entity.

---

So, I'm bit lost here. This works, so it's "ok" i guess, but it looks very dirty. I have not found a way to allow somekind of `InteractiveSystem` to take care of item using without adding huge complexity issues ( Those arise quickly when you try to force Entity system to do something it does not easily allow ).

So, question is:

**How to decouple this so, that i don't have to pass Entity to component?**

I just don't feel good about the current code but so far it's the best solution we have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am passing entity to Use method, because using something can alter
>   the entity. It could add component to it, check if it has certain
>   component and then modify the data or remove components, it could even
>   remove the entity.

So you're passing the `Entity` to `Use` because `Use` could (effectively) "do anything" with the entity, but you want to come up with a way to *not* pass the entity?

This is pretty straightforward: *change your design*. Define more concretely what you want `Use` to be permitted to do to a thing, and pass it a reference to some interface exposing what it is allowed to do. Otherwise accept that your current design needs the entity in `Use` because `Use` is allowed to do almost anything to an entity.

There are lots of different ways you could reorganize this to make it look or feel different, but fundamentally if your fixed principle is that "using a a thing can *mutate the using entity*, you're going to need to give it the entity, and what you have now seems like a reasonably straightforward approach to that (your dependencies in `Use` are explicit; this is a *good thing*).

Comment: Passing entity to component method ( even thou that method is actually Item objects method) is my concern. And yes, item could do anything for the entity, even destroy it.  I wonder if somekind of event system could help? I could maybe set some event up, that entity a is using entity b and then some system could pick up that event and handle it ( and set that system run last)?  My first project with Entity framework and  it surely needs a bit different mindset. Your answer certainly gave me more confidence on my current setup. Thanks

Comment: An "event system" is also an option but won't change the fundamental thing going on; it will only obfuscate the relationship between the action and it's dependencies more.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. Thanks for your time. Your answer kickstarted me to mindstorming phase. I realize now, even thou i have been here for quite some time already, this is something i could have handled in the chat. I will keep the item system as it is and just stop forcing everything to component system pairs.